# create a file if does not exist, if exist do not overwrite the values

Tags: python, file, overwrite

I would like to do following:

1. Create a test.csv if does not exist
2. Write some values in it (see the code)
3. Merge test.csv with data.csv and save as test.csv
4. Run the same script, but the file names are changed / replaced (data.csv to data2.csv)
5. Create a test.csv if does not exist (now it exist)
6. Write some values in it (see the code), but do not overwrite the current values in the data, just add them

Here is my code:

```
    #create a file if does not exist
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    myseries=pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
    os.chdir(r"G:\..")
    file = open('test.csv', 'a+')
    df = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['values'])
    df.to_csv("test.csv" , index=False)
    -----------------
    # merge with data.csv
    -------------
    # create a file if does not exist, if exist write new values without overwritting the existing ones    
    myseries=pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
    os.chdir(r"G:\..")
    file = open('test.csv', 'a+')
    df = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['values'])
    df.to_csv("test.csv" , index=False)
    # the values after merge were deleted and replaced with the new data
```

I have tried a, a+, w, w+, but the current data in the file were replaced with the new ones.
How could be defined, that new data are writting into csv without removing the current data?

Comment: Please explain how `"a"` did not meet requirements.

Comment: Its better if we can run your code. An example without `os.chdir` could be tested by those of us using linux.

Comment: The file test.csv consists one column. Now i would like to add another column with: `myseries=pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
os.chdir(r"G:\...")
file = open('test.csv', 'a')
df = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['values'])
df.to_csv("test.csv" , index=False)` But it just write the new values in the test.csv while removing the original column

Comment: Have a look at python3's pathlib, which offers `exists()` and also an `open()` function

Comment: Adding a new column means re-writing the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.to_csv()` does not care about the mode in which the file is opened using `open()` and will overwrite the file anyway. Instead to append rows at the end of an existing csv file, you can use the `file.wite()` method.

```
# For concatenation, remove the headers or they will show up as a row
contents = df.to_csv(index = False, header=False)
file = open("test.csv",'a')
file.write(contents)
file.close()
```

Or you could read, concat and rewrite the file

```
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
test = pd.concat([test, df])
test.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```

To append columns, you can set the axis to 1.

```
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
test = pd.concat([test, df], axis=1)
test.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: `df.to_csv()` without the filename returns the string which is to be written

Comment: `myseries=pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
os.chdir(r"G:\..")
file = open('test.csv', 'a')
df = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['values'])
contents = df.to_csv(index = False, header=False)
file.write(contents)
file.close()` Could you please be more specific? I have tried this one, but it keeps the original data unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean by original data is unchanged? After you run this code, 5 random numbers will be appended in `test.csv`.